# Wordpress author's page is not showing all posts written by the author

Tags: wordpress

I run a Wordpress Multisite installation with the Shineblog theme on it. On authors pages, not all posts written by the author are displayed.

Example:
Author: Sophie Gaitzsch

Her site:
https://www.horizons-mag.ch/author/sophiegaitzsch/

Only one post is listed, this one:
https://www.horizons-mag.ch/2017/06/18/machines-that-listen/

But there is a second post written by her:
https://www.horizons-mag.ch/2017/12/19/the-genomic-traveller/
Her name on this posts is linked correctly to her author's site. But the post itself is not displayed there.

This behaviour is the same in all three languages (we serve English, German and French). Several authors show this behaviour; Sophie Gaitzsch is just an example.

It is a WP multisite installation. We use the Shineblog theme which I modified, but always in a child-theme directory.

As far as I know I never touched the WP loop so I don't know if this a Wordpress problem or a frontend problem or a database problem.

If I should post any code please let me know.

Comment: Hi, this page is coded in the author.php or check in setting of theme is there any way to set the limit of post for author page or have you customized the author.php

Comment: Thanks a lot. So far I found out it is a problem caused by the theme we bought and installed (Shineblog theme). Installing a default WP theme makes this bug disappear.

Also installing the Shineblog theme on another Wordpress made the same bug appear there, too.

So I will wait for feedback from the theme's developer team. Or try my best with the theme's archive-php

Thanks again.

Comment: ok hope the theme developer help this out!